# How do i experimentally determine the vapour pressure of a solution?

Tags: physical-chemistry, vapor-pressure

So i wanna dissolve different salts in water and measure the vapour pressure of the resulting solution. I am doing this to compare the freezing point depression of different cations, used with the same anion and in the same concen for the experiment, as well a smaller vapour pressure implies greater freezing point depression. How would I go about this? I know the apparatus available to us is a gas pressure sensor but not much about how to utilize it.

Note: If possible, I dont want to use Raoult's Law.

Comment: How are you going to find out the freezing point depression by measuring the vapour pressure? And please give your own thoughts about how this could be done. There is a big problem if you have nothing but a pressure sensor. What is it?

Comment: It seems to me he wants to relate ebulioscopy and kryoscopy via respective constants. But it seems to me like  *"scrabbing himself behind his right ear by the left hand"* .

Comment: @Poutnik Ja, and like a physchem lab course where they haven't given out experiment descriptions. Novel idea, that.

Comment: @Karl I remember doing the experiment described in my answer, determining water p=f(T) curve in the first year of my undergraduate studies within the lab about laboratory techniques. ( 1984 )

Comment: @Poutnik The most interesting part here was always the quantitative(ly correct) error analysis. ;-)

Comment: @Karl  Yes, e.g. proper linearization for the linear regression.

Comment: @Karl I wont be directly finding out, but dissolving the salt decreases vapour pressure right? So im gonna compare the vapour pressure for different solutions. The greater the dip, the lower the freezing point.

Comment: @Poutnik I have no idea how to find vapor pressure tbh... how would you do it? im only in high school so i know none of those constants xD. What do you mean by "scrabbing himself behind his right eye by the left hand". The general idea is to form 5 solutions with diff salts of equal concen and measure their vapor pressure. the lower the vapour pressure, the greater the freezing point depression.

Comment: Why not to directly measure decreased freezing point ?

Comment: @Raze XIX The ebulioscopic/cryoscopic constant ( Wikipedia ) relates molality of solution and change of voiling/freezing point. Byt the "scrabbing...." I mean aiming for a complex setup to measure pressures instead of easy setup to measure temperature. Also, instead of changed vapour pressure, it is easier to measure the changed boiling point.

Comment: @Poutnik because i need to use really small concentrations and the freezing point depression constant is really low, like 1.89. hence the freezing point depression or elevation is only... like 0.2, so there is too much error. what do u suggest i do? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create a vacuum enduring  apparatus, equipped with a heated flask with the solution, with constrained capillary air inlet immersed into the liquid ( provides boiling centers to avoit overheating ) and pressure sensor, attached to a vacuum source.

Combination of applied heating and vacuum, there will be established "laboratory grade equilibrium", where the measure pressure is the saturated vapor tension at the measured temperature.